# Loss of Margin Spacing on Fixed Layout

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS from Jon Duckett's book and have encountered a problem with the fixed layout example in Chapter 15.  I was messing around and put in another  to try completely understand this layout.  My problem is the new  I put in seems to not honor the margin: 10px; rule (at least I think it is the margin-top).

Here is my example:

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2syjwchy/)

Example From the Book: "A Fixed Width Layout": [EXAMPLE](http://htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-15/fixed-width-layout.html)

HTML

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #665544;
 text-align: center;
    }
    body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* top/bottom left/right*/
    }
    #content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    }
    #nav, #feature, #footer, #test /*This ID*/ {
    background-color: #efefef;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    }
    #article_column1, #article_column2, #article_column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    }
    li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    a{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="feature">
      <p>Feature</p>
    </div>
    <!--Problem Starts Here-->
    <div id="test">
      <p>Why is your margin-top so small?</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Problem Ends Here -->
    <div id="article_column1">
      <p>Column One</p>
    </div>
    <div id="article_column2">
      <p>Column Two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="article_column3">
      <p>Column Three</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2011</p>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I think outlining the problem would help as we don't have the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with "margin collapsing" from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing):

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed)
>   into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined
>   into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

**Update:**

The best way to override this phenom is to add an element inbetween to break the collapsing:

`<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;">.</div>`

Updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qw357za9/)**

Comment: I was reading and found some more info from SitePoint. This is hard for me to understand since all the margins on this page are set to 10px, so there is "no" bigger margin to use and a smaller margin to throw out (is there?). I found an okay solution by creating a new CSS rule: #test {background-color: #eee000; margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px; padding: 10px;}. Is this a correct solution? My problem here is that how would I calculate the 20px margin-top? I just guessed and it looks similar to 10px I guess. Here is the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oa3xeg59/):

Comment: Here the "largest" is simply 10px, since neither one is larger than the other. To answer your second question, you can compensate for the collapsed margin by adding it to the margin of the second element. So here both had a margin of 10px and you just combined them to 20px. The better solution is to clear them. See my edits above.

Comment: Wow, this is a great and clean solution.  Thank you, and everyone, for the help.  Now I can move onto the next example instead of reading online for a solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. And don't forget to click the checkbox to accept my answer if it has solved your problem ;)